# How to find out which classes/paths are provided by container?

Tags: path, export, wildfly, system, classloading

I am using WildFly 10.1 and need to add several modules. Of course they have their own dependencies which I need to define in `module.xml`. As far as I know, some classes are already provided by container itself (e.g. class `javax/xml/ws/Service`) and to add a dependency to this system library I used to put the following in `module.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <system export="true">
        <paths>
            <path name="javax/xml/ws"/>
            <path name="javax/xml/namespace"/>
        </paths>
    </system>
</dependencies>
```

Meanwhile, I am doing this *just because I know this*.

But what if I will face the situation somewhere in the future when I am not sure whether this particular class is provided by container/JDK or not? **How can I find out the complete list** of classes / paths that I can export from current container (system) / JDK?

I have surfed through lots of articles and documentation dedicated to classloading in WildFly and most of them just state you can do those `system export="true"`, but was unable to find any hint of the answer to such question.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably shouldn't add system paths like that, but rather depend on the `javax.api` module.

Comment: Any explanation why it could be bad idea? For some reason `javax.api` module doesn't provide `javax/xml/ws` and thus I am getting classNotFound for `javax/xml/ws/Service`, that's why I ended up adding system paths like that. Anyways thanks, I will go and learn a bit more on this.

Comment: You'd end up with say `javax.xml.ws.Service` in two different class loaders which has potential to cause issues. What you likely want is a dependency on `javax.api` and `javax.xml.ws.api`.

Comment: Finally I have found out that I don't need those modules at all, my mistake was to put a second jar into one module with the other JAR (which is really required), and that's why codeflow went the wrong way throwing me ClassNotFound exceptions making me to add more and more modules. I have removed those extra JAR from the module and everything worked like a charm then (in fact it was already bundled into the related EAR). Meanwhile, I am still curious about the answer to the initial question.